# OpenLayers Load XYZ-Tiles from high zoom levels on lower zoom levels

Tags: dictionary, zooming, openlayers

**Context**

Hi guys. If have a TileXYZ source in OpenLayers, which delivers on low zoom levels blank images (until zoom level 11) and then (>=11) the actual tiles. But I want OpenLayers to load the tiles from high zoom levels at lower zoom levels. This will increase my traffic, but the user won't have to zoom that far in to see stuff. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

My code implementing the TileXYZ-Source:

```
 overlayLayer = new OlTileLayer({
      source: new OlXYZ({
        url: layer.URL1 + layer.Version + layer.URL2 + layer.Version + layer.URL3,
      }),
      opacity: layer.Opacity,
      visible: true
    })
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ol/source/XYZ` has a `minZoom` option:

```
 overlayLayer = new OlTileLayer({
      source: new OlXYZ({
        url: layer.URL1 + layer.Version + layer.URL2 + layer.Version + layer.URL3,
        minZoom: 11,
      }),
      opacity: layer.Opacity,
      visible: true
    })
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick for me ... I want to sort of display the tiles from level 11 on those levels <11

Comment: That is what will happen (`minZoom` on the source is not the same as `minZoom` on the layer)